# Scale Sections of Data to between -1 and 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Working with a 2D signal/time series dataset, after finding peaks and troughs, I would like to scale each section of the dataset appropriately.

For example, if I have the following visual dataset, with peaks and troughs labeled as such:

[image: BeginningPeakAndTroughLabels]

...what's a good "pythonic" way to label every other datapoint between each peak and trough to be a number > -1 and < 1, sort of like so:

[image: IdealAnsweredDataset]

I have provided a reproducible code below to experiment with.

NOTE: I'm running Windows 10, Python 3.10.5.

`pip install findpeaks`

```
from numpy import array, inf, nan, where
# pip install findpeaks
from findpeaks import findpeaks
from random import gauss, seed
from math import sqrt, exp

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
#                                    GENERATE RANDOM SIGNAL DATA                                   #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
# https://towardsdatascience.com/create-a-stock-price-simulator-with-python-b08a184f197d
def create_GBM(s0, mu, sigma):
    """
    Generates a price following a geometric brownian motion process based on the input of the arguments:
    - s0: Asset inital price.
    - mu: Interest rate expressed annual terms.
    - sigma: Volatility expressed annual terms. 
    """
    st = s0
    def generate_value():
        nonlocal st
        st *= exp((mu - 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * (1. / 365.) + sigma * sqrt(1./365.) * gauss(mu=0, sigma=1))
        return st
    return generate_value

gbm = create_GBM(100, 0.001, 1.0)

signal = [round(gbm(), 2) for _ in range(10000)]
print(signal)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
#                                 FIND PEAKS AND TROUGHS DATAFRAME                                 #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
print("Finding peaks/troughs....")
fp = findpeaks(method='peakdetect')
results = fp.fit(array(signal).flatten())
results_df = results['df']
results_df['label'] = where(results_df['valley'], -1, 
                            where(results_df['peak'], 1, nan))
print(results_df)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
#                 FILL NAN's WITH THEIR APPROPRIATE VALUES, SCALED BETWEEN -1 and 1                #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
# ????????????????????????????
```

Given that the `results_df` gives the `y` values, along with some `x` indexes on where they are, I was hoping there'd be a one-liner for this.

Another thought I had would be to iterate through the results df, peak to trough, then trough to peak (repeat) and `MinMaxScale` everything between the start and end of each section, as we know what those values are. Something like:

[image: Idea]

**UPDATE**

I have a hacky solution here, HOWEVER IT'S NOT WORKING! So treat it as pseudo-code for now, but it looks like this so far. I feel there's an easier way...

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
#                 FILL NAN's WITH THEIR APPROPRIATE VALUES, SCALED BETWEEN -1 and 1                #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
# Drop nan's from label column to make things easier for iteration
results_df = results_df.dropna()
print(results_df)

# Iterate through the results_df, starting at 1, not 0
for i in range(1, len(results_df)):
    
    # Find the current values for this "section" of the signal dataset
    if results_df['label'].iloc[i] > 0:
        peak_value = results_df['y'].iloc[i]
        peak_value_index = results_df['x'].iloc[i]
        trough_value = results_df['y'].iloc[i-1]
        trough_value_index = results_df['x'].iloc[i-1]
    else:
        peak_value = results_df['y'].iloc[i-1]
        peak_value_index = results_df['x'].iloc[i-1]
        trough_value = results_df['y'].iloc[i]
        trough_value_index = results_df['x'].iloc[i]
    
    # Find the current min value
    current_min_value = min(peak_value, trough_value)
    
    # Find the difference between the max and min values
    current_difference = max(peak_value, trough_value) - min(peak_value, trough_value)
    
    # Now iterate through that "section" of the signal list, and scale accordingly
    for j in range(min(peak_value_index, trough_value_index), max(peak_value_index, trough_value_index)+1): # +1 to ensure last datapoint isn't missed
        signal[j] = (signal[j] - current_min_value) / current_difference - 1

# Inspect the newly scaled signals at the peak/trough points to ensure they're correct
for i in range(0, len(results_df)):
    print(signal[results_df['x'].iloc[i]])
```

[image: problem]

Comment: Are you saying you want different segments of the plot to have different scale/offsets?  How is that useful?  It's tricky to decide whether a peak is just a local maximum or is a global peak.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean? I want each `y` value on the plot to be scaled between -1 and 1, in relation to its previous and next peak/trough? So any `y` value will be a float between `-1 and 1`. Example, starting from the first `-1` on the left, and going to the first `1`, all those values should be scaled between `-1` and `1`. Then, going from `1` down to the second `-1`, the numbers would be scaled from `1` to `-1`.

Comment: Also, don't worry about the local minima issue. or offsets of any kind. Just need the values scaled as described. Thanks!

Comment: `scipy.signal.find_peaks` can find peaks.  Once you have the peaks, the scaling part is easy.

Comment: It's the scaling I'm looking for. I'm using a different `find_peaks` package as it's more in line with my real use case (it performed better than scipy's version), so I need help with the scaling part only

Comment: OK, here's an example of what I mean.  After the -1 in the middle, it goes up and then down.  How do we know that "down" is not another peak?

Comment: ...because the peaks and troughs are determined ahead of time? The findpeaks package does that for you already. Don't worry about that, just assume the peaks and troughs are where they're supposed to be.

Comment: Well, if you have a segment where it starts with a high peak of +7 and ends with -5, then you have a range of 12.    So, you subtract -5 (making the range 0..12), divide by 6 (making the range 0..2), and subtract 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246687/discussion-between-matt-wilson-and-tim-roberts).

Comment: I don't like that policy.  If I'm helping, I want to help others as well.

Comment: Well, stack doesn't like extended discussions in comments...anyway here's what I mean:

Comment: I want to make sure you understand what I'm trying to accomplish here. When using the findpeaks package on the entire 2D signal, it figures out where the peaks and troughs are, and I have it set to give a 1 for a peak value, and a -1 for a trough. The raw y values are all above 0, think like stock prices would be the best way to describe it. There is never +7 and -5 or whatever you're thinking...

Comment: The same processing applies if the raw values are 75 and 50.  You would subtract the low value from all of them (50), divide by half the difference (12,5), and subtract 1.  Now your range is -1 to +1.

Comment: So:

y = 60 --> y = 60 - 50 --> y = 10 --> y = 10 / 12.5 --> y = 0.8 --> y = 0.8 - 1 --> y = -0.2

Comment: Right!  That is its proportional spot if 75..50 is mapped to 1..-1.

Comment: I feel as though MinMaxScaler would do this for us haha I'm working on a solution now...Nevermind, no it won't! I think manual formula way will work for this...

Comment: I made an update with a not working solution lol take a look when you can and edit accordingly. I am heading home now so will check again in the morning. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code can be found below. There are two remarks:

1. My implementation is a variation on your approach with two notable differences. First, I directly iterate through the segments and find these indices outside of the for-loop. Second, your transformation seems to be missing a factor 2. That is, I take transformation = -1 + 2* (value-min)/(max-min) to ensure that transformed value takes the value +1 whenever value=max.
2. I also added some code to plot the original series and its transformation together. This allows us to visually check whether the transformation was successful. In general, the transformation seems to be working but it does happen occasionally that the peak detection algorithm misses a peak/trough. The transformation will now receive the wrong input and the result of the transformation is no longer guaranteed to be in the [-1,1] interval.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from numpy import argwhere, array, inf, isnan, nan, transpose, where, zeros
# pip install findpeaks
from findpeaks import findpeaks
from random import gauss, seed
from math import sqrt, exp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
#                                    GENERATE RANDOM SIGNAL DATA                                   #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
# https://towardsdatascience.com/create-a-stock-price-simulator-with-python-b08a184f197d
def create_GBM(s0, mu, sigma):
    """
    Generates a price following a geometric brownian motion process based on the input of the arguments:
    - s0: Asset inital price.
    - mu: Interest rate expressed annual terms.
    - sigma: Volatility expressed annual terms.
    """
    st = s0
    def generate_value():
        nonlocal st
        st *= exp((mu - 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * (1. / 365.) + sigma * sqrt(1./365.) * gauss(mu=0, sigma=1))
        return st
    return generate_value

gbm = create_GBM(100, 0.001, 1.0)

signal = [round(gbm(), 2) for _ in range(10000)]
print(signal)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
#                                 FIND PEAKS AND TROUGHS DATAFRAME                                 #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
print("Finding peaks/troughs....")
fp = findpeaks(method='peakdetect')
results = fp.fit(array(signal).flatten())
results_df = results['df']
results_df['label'] = where(results_df['valley'], -1,
                            where(results_df['peak'], 1, nan))
print(results_df)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
#                 FILL NAN's WITH THEIR APPROPRIATE VALUES, SCALED BETWEEN -1 and 1                #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #

# Convert some results to numpy arrays
label = results_df["label"].to_numpy()
y = transpose(results_df["y"].to_numpy())

# Indices to beginning and ends of segments
indices = argwhere(~isnan(label))

# Initialize output
signal =  zeros( (len(results_df),1) )

# Compute signal for all segments
for segment in range(1,len(indices)):

    # Indices of current segments
    start_index = indices[segment-1][0]
    end_index = indices[segment][0]

    # Determine through and peak value
    yvalue_start = y[start_index]
    yvalue_end = y[end_index]

    # Determine through and peak values
    if yvalue_start<yvalue_end:
        trough_value = yvalue_start
        peak_value = yvalue_end
    else:
        trough_value = yvalue_end
        peak_value = yvalue_start
    current_difference = peak_value-trough_value

    # Inform user
    print("Segment {} from index {} to {} with trough={} and peak={}".format(segment, start_index, end_index, trough_value, peak_value))


    signal[start_index:(end_index+1), 0] = -1.0 + (2/current_difference) * (y[start_index:(end_index+1)]-trough_value)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1)
axs[0].plot(y)
axs[0].set_title('Original series')
axs[1].plot(signal)
axs[1].set_title('Converted signal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Great work! And the scaling not being between -1 and 1 for EVERY point is actually relatively ok, so long as MOST points are scaled, it’s fine. Thank you!